# Trying to multiply two numbers and put the result in a "RichTextBox"VB.net

Tags: vb.net

So I have a salary counting interface, and I need to multiply 'DailyPay' and 'total' then put all the infos in a RichTextBox,at first I got this error:
'Conversion from string "Employee ID: 4 Employee Name:" to type 'Double' is not valid.' FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
then I declared DailyPay and total as strings, the data got displayed in the richtextbox but it's not multiplying the numbers cuz the DailyPay is empty so the total amount is always 0.(Salarybox is the RichTextBox name)

```
 Private Sub Guna2Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guna2Button1.Click
    Dim DailyPay As Integer


    Try
        If empposition.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Select an Employee")
        ElseIf wdays.Text = "" Or Convert.ToInt32(wdays.Text) > 28 Then
            MsgBox("Enter a valid Number of Days")
        Else
            If empposition.Text = "Receptionist" Then
                DailyPay = 120
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Reception manager" Then
                DailyPay = 200
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "House keeping manager" Then
                DailyPay = 100
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Bar manager" Then
                DailyPay = 200
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Barman" Then
                DailyPay = 130
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Waiter" Then
                DailyPay = 100
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Vendor" Then
                DailyPay = 125
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Shop manager" Then
                DailyPay = 200
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "IT manager" Then
                DailyPay = 200
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Technicien" Then
                DailyPay = 120
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Spa manager" Then
                DailyPay = 180
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Beautician" Then
                DailyPay = 80
            ElseIf empposition.Text = "Security man" Then
                DailyPay = 100
            End If
            Dim total = DailyPay * Convert.ToInt32(wdays.Text)
            Salarybox.Text = "Employee ID:   " & empid.Text & vbLf & "Employee Name:   " & ename.Text & vbLf & "Employee LastName:   " & lastname.Text & vbLf & "Position:   " & empposition.Text & vbLf & "Worked Days:   " & wdays.Text & vbLf & "Daily Salary:   " & Convert.ToString(DailyPay) & vbLf & "Total Amount:   " & Convert.ToString(total)
        End If
    Catch Ovex As OverflowException
        MsgBox("Number is too large")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try


End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NomY4.png)

Comment: Set `Option Strict` to `ON` and fix everything that's squiggling. You'll get it right.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I did it but I still have the same problem

Comment: Then post the code you have come up with after you have set `Option Strict On`.

Comment: I kept the same code as the one above, with every change I did to the code I came up with an error

Comment: `Option Strict` doesn't allow that code to run (it's also clearly wrong). You have to learn to use correct Data Types,  e.g., you cannot sum integers with strings. So start over, declare both `DailyPay` and 
`total`  as numeric values (if you have numbers with decimal places, use the `Decimal` Type, not `Integer`) -- Also, use `[Type].TryParse()` (e.g., `Integer.TryParse()`) to convert a value contained in a TextBox (User input in general), so you also validate it at the same time. -- Side note: the RichTextBox Control uses a line feed to separate lines of text, so use `vbLf`, not `vbCrLf`.

Comment: I'm just a beginner at coding so these concepts are still a bit confusing to me but thank you I understand

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really stuck in this (I know it's silly), but whatever I try it gives me the same error I don't know what to do exactly

Comment: As mentioned, you need to set `Option Strict` to `ON`. If, after that, you have a some (a lot) of *errors*, it's because now the errors are recognized **before** the application is run instead of after. You need to fix them in any case -- Also, remember that the string concatenation token in VB.Net is `&`, not `+`. With `Option Strict OFF`, using the `+` token, you can (will) have very *strange* outcomes. -- If you want some help, you need to specify your VB.Net version and the .Net version you're targeting, since the available tools change quite a lot.

Comment: You also need to say whether this is a school assignment of something like it, because you may need to use specific tools and not others. For example, I'd replace all those `If` / `ElseIf` with a `Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)`, `MsgBox` should not be used and input errors should be presented using the `ErrorProvider` class.

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me, it's a school project and my supervisor asked me to use visual basic even tho I never studied the language, I'm using the last version of the .Net and VB.Net. I took the method I used for this code from a tuto and it worked for them, also I searched for all the other possible ways to fix it but nothing really helped

Comment: @Jimi So I used the breakpoint and changed the code a bit and I guess I have the problem in DailyPay since it returns just 0 but I don't know how to fix that, I added a picture description so that u can see the problem

Comment: Take your time to watch some tutorials, learn a bit the basic syntax and concepts of the language etc. before trying to write your first program - otherwise your are only going to be frustrated.